# Backup файлов на кириллице

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование

Как в Linux сделать скрипт бекапа файлов с кириллическими символами в пути (находятся такие в директориях Samba, доступных для редактирования по сети от пользователей Windows)

Comment: абсолютно точно так же, как и для любых других файлов. ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Если система поддерживает UTF-8 при создании файлов, то 99% поддерживает их копирование, соответственно, обычный `cp -a`, `rsync` и так далее будут работать.

Comment: Не вышло с cp
Приведу свой пример. 
Источник лежит здесь:
/disk2/Proizvodstvo/1. Планы/План 2019.xls

Делаю скрипт:
#!/bin/sh
cp -a '/disk2/Proizvodstvo/1. Планы/План 2019.xls' /disk2/Plan/plan_`date +%y-%m-%d`.xls

Выдаётся ошибка:

cp: невозможно выполнить stat для «/disk2/Proizvodstvo/1. \317\353\340\355\373/\317\353\340\355 2019.xls»: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: @Максим, скрипт сохраняй в utf-8, а не в cp1251... и, предупреждая следующую проблему, с unix'овым концом строки....

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена